# How many instructions does this method use to find the least value in the table?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, big-o

```
public static int min1(int[] a) { 
if (a.length < 1)
throw new IllegalArgumentException("a is empty"); 

int m = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
if (a[i] < a[m]) m = i;
}

return m;
}
```

The input given:

```
a = {4, 17, 10, 6, 1, 15, 3, 18}
```

I tried to solve this step by step. Looking at each simple expression and the for-loop. If statement -> 2 int m = 0 -> 2 (declaration and initialization). I ended up with 48 steps for an answer.

I've heard  that there is a possibility to simplify this to the function:

```
6(n-1)+x+9
```

Where n is the total elements in the array and where x is the number of times the if-statement occurs which is one. I understand that this method has a O(n) runtime.
The correct answer is 52.

I would like to understand how we can derive to that function. The logic behind it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a "step" and how did you get to 48/52 ?

Comment: How did you arrive at that correct answer?  It looks like a single pass over the array to me.

Comment: @alfasin step is one instruction. If statement takes two steps. As it takes in the length of the array and compares it to 1.

Comment: and "taking the length of an array" is considered as one step ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The if-statement is two steps (a.length and comparison). int m = 0 is two steps too. initialization and assignment.  The for loop will run (n-1) times. There is 8 elements in the array. etc. The if statement in the array is two steps I believe.

Comment: @alfasin that's what I believe. a.length  is one step and comparison is one step. 2 steps total. Instruction is a better choice of words I guess.

Comment: Your belief is not true. Unless you're referring to bytecode instructions... as long as you're referring to Java, reading a value is not considered as an instruction. Assignment, comparison, arithmetic operation, bitwise operation and etc - these are considered as "instructions" or "steps".

Comment: If you're looking for complexity as a function of the input size, it looks linear to me i.e. `O(n)`, which means as the array input grows arbitrarily large, the performance will scale to the size.  The other small steps you highlighted are not that relevant from a running time point of view.